# How to properly size a MenuBarExtra menu icon with a custom image in SwiftUI for macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm trying to better understand how to create a MenuBarExtra in SwiftUI for macOS.  The new MenuBarExtra scene is very easy to get started with, particularly if you're only looking to use an SF Symbol for your icon.  However, I'm running in to trouble using a custom image.

If I point the MenuBarExtra at the image in my Assets, it doesn't do any of its own scaling and the image appears massive in the menu bar.  I found that if I use MenuBarExtra(content:label:) then I can at least apply .renderingMode(.template) to my image, but none of the typical SwiftUI re-sizing works and the icon always appears massive.

I tried adjusting the original image size down to a 16x16 and 32x32 for 2x, which does make the icon fit properly, but it's still really pixelated and poor quality.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct menubartestappApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        MenuBarExtra {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .padding()
        } label: {
            Image("frond-icon")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 16, height: 16, alignment: .center)
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.menu)
```

I'm actually re-using the same icon that we used for our previous NoMAD deployment, which has always look clean and crisp in the menu bar.  Here's what the icons look like next to each other:

No modifications to the image, the one on the right is the MenuBarExtra and is using the same source image as the one on the left:

[image: right side is the MenuBarExtra app]

The one on the right is the same source image as the one of the left, but resized down to 16x16:

[image: right side is the MenuBarExtra app]

Please let me know what I'm missing here.  I'd like to scale the higher quality image down to look like the old NoMAD icon.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I have since discovered that the low res image isn't just the menu icon.  I added five other fairly high-res icons which, upon closer inspection, actually display quite low-res.  They're properly sized according to my layout, but if you look closely, especially on a Retina display, they're way more pixelated than they should be.

Any ideas why all my images are so low-res in my MenuBarExtra app?  I've played with different compressions, but there doesn't seem to be any noticeable change.  I'm new to SwiftUI and to macOS development particularly, so I appreciate any and all assistance here.

[image: otherLowResPics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Removing the `1x` version of the image fixed it for me.

I was running into the same problem, where the app was using the `1x` version of the image instead of the `2x`:

[image: Screen Box's icon in low resolution]

After [searching on SourceGraph](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context%3Aglobal%20MenuBarExtra%28&patternType=standard&sm=1&groupBy=repo) for uses of `MenuBarExtra`, I found a couple examples using `MenuBarExtra("Title", image: "MenuBarIcon")`, and their `Assets.xcassets` folder didn't have a `1x` version of the images. So I removed it, and the icon is no longer pixelated:

[image: Screen Box's icon in high resolution]

I also tested changing my monitor's resolution to one that should use the `1x` version, to ensure it wouldn't show an icon bigger than it should, and the icon was still consistent with the others.

Comment: Holy coding, Batman!  Thank you, that definitely solved my menu bar icon issue and it looks great now.  However, it only solved the menu icon and I'm still having issues with my other assets, which are very high quality original .pngs, but the app still shows them in the same pixelated way.  

Answer (score 3):

This [article](https://mirzoyan.dev/mirzoyan%20dev%20d62e6ab9344e4ab8a9c14205257ea2cc/Blog%20208f3509a5b74655b973d4dbaaf500e6/Custom%20icon%20for%20SwiftUI%20MenuBarExtra%20fdd31ec3e0af46adb3f7f69129bd6172) works for me (Xcode 15, minimum macOS 13.0):

> We initialize an NSImage scale it and then use it to initialize a SwiftUI Image. Unfortunately NSImage cannot respect image ratio so we calculate it manually:

```swift
MenuBarExtra {
    ContentView()
} label: {
    let image: NSImage = {
        let ratio = $0.size.height / $0.size.width
        $0.size.height = 18
        $0.size.width = 18 / ratio
        return $0
    }(NSImage(named: "logo")!)

    Image(nsImage: image)
}
```